# How keep or remember of set date even though page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When we call 1st time we get the start date of today.Then we wants to set new date and we want to keep the new set date after we call 2nd times.I don't know how to keep history data of date that we set and want to use again.

```
setCalendar: function() {
    var inqYYYY = todate.substring(0, 4);
    var inqMM = todate.substring(4, 6);
    var inqDD = todate.substring(6, 8);
    var inqStrDt = formatter.date(webank.date_minus(todate, 6));
    var inqEndDt = inqYYYY + "-" + inqMM + "-" + inqDD;

    datePicker.setCalendar("#inq_str_dt");
    $("#inq_str_dt").val(inqStrDt);
    datePicker.setCalendar("#inq_end_dt");
    $("#inq_end_dt").val(inqEndDt);
}
```

Comment: When you say "session data", you mean if the user leaves the site and comes back, the data is still there? Or just remembering what was selected across multiple calls to `setCalendar`?

Comment: localStorage or session storage.

Comment: It just remembering what was selected across multiple calls to setCalendar?

Comment: Create a cookie and set the delete time as per your requirement.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `inqStrDt` and `inqEndDt` into a [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ( A persistent storage having lifetime till reset browser storage and history).

You can set the value by

```
localStorage.setItem('inqStrDt ', inqStrDt);
```

You can read accoringly as well

```
let startDate =  localStorage.getItem('inqStrDt ');
if(startDate ) {
    \\do something
}
```